# Docker volumes and how to copy files between local and container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file with the relevant volumes section:

```
my-service:
   container_name: my-container
   ...
   volumes:
     - /host-dir:/container-dir
```

I want the contents of container-dir (configuration files) to be copied to host-dir on deploy, but only if the relevant file does not already exist. If it does, then the copying should always be from that file in /host-dir to that file in /container-dir.

The use case is to simplify the initial deploy, so that it's fully automated from a CI/CD pipeline without the need for additional intervention.

Is this possible, ideally using only docker-compose functionality? If not, how might one accomplish it?

Comment: "*I want the contents of container-dir to be copied to host-dir*" - If the container does not have an init-script that copies something to `/container-dir`, then the `/container-dir` will always have the content of the `/host-dir`. This is how volumes work: if they are mounted on a directory, that already holds data, the volume "shadows" the data present.

Comment: "*The use case is to simplify the initial deploy*" - Wouldn't it be much easier to just build a ready-to-go container image and deploy that, maybe with some environment variables to configure the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a named volume with bind mount options. That way you get the behavior described here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted such as /app/, the directory’s contents are copied into the volume. The container then mounts and uses the volume, and other containers which use the volume also have access to the pre-populated content.

```
services:
  my-service:
     volumes:
       - my-volume:/container-dir

volumes:
  my-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /path/to/host-dir
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. In case anyone else runs into this, I had to pre-create the host directory, and also chmod -R the permissions of the container files (in the Dockerfile) so I could edit them; this is perhaps peculiar to the circumstances of the deploy from the CI/CD pipeline.